# background or background color?

Tags: css, background

What is this best practice to use that's most compatible across multiple browsers:

```
background:#ffffff;
```

or

```
background-color:#ffffff;
```

or is it best to use both to cover more:

```
background:#ffffff;
background-color:#ffffff;
```

Comment: Its both compatible but if you only want to apply color to your background I personally would use "background-color".

Comment: background-color is more preferable

Comment: There is in fact a difference if you have something like: background: url(bg.png) repeat-y #FFFFFF;  The difference is that the repeat-x direction would be filled up with white. You can also achieve this by using background-image, background-repeat, background-color etc... Background is simply a way of combining all background properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference about compatibility. The only difference is that using `background` you could add several properties in the same line, as you probably know, instead of repeating `background-color`, `backgroud-image` etc in different lines.

Answer (score 1):

To set the color, you can use either of these.

As per W3C Standards, we shall follow the `background-color` property. However, if you follow this, you will be only able to add color and not other options like `size, image, attachment` etc.
I would suggest you to go for standard format as it is easy for others to clearly read about the properties.

You can learn more about the background property from:

[W3C Schools - Background Property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer background-color. My first reason is readability because in a first glance you can know what's the purpose of that style. When you use plain "background" you can define many properties inside it which makes it more complicated to read.

```
Background: color position/size repeat origin clip attachment image|initial|inherit;
```

versus `background-color: color|transparent|initial|inherit;`

And ie is not fully compatible with all background properties:

> Note: IE8 and earlier do not support multiple background images on one
>   element.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter if you use `background` or `background-color` since `background` is a prefix/shortcut to:

```
-color
-image
-position
-attachment
-repeat
```

Its just that using `background` can let you add its additional css properties to prevent repetition of declarations. It is one of the basics of CSS. But if you are only going to change the color of the background and nothing else, I recommend you use `background-color`.